# Textarea in Chrome and Safari, all visible line breaks sent to server

Tags: php, html, textarea

I've ran into a bit of trouble trying to input data into my mysql db using Chrome and Safari. When ever I input data from either of these browsers the data sent into the db is showing breaks where the edge of the textarea field is. So intead of having one long line of text it's broken over a few lines.

I'm running `stripslashes` and `strip_tags` for when the data goes into the DB. It works fine in FF & IE.

See below to see what I mean:

Text input field:
http://www.redcontour.com/query/textarea_field.png

Chrome & Safari DB entry:
http://redcontour.com/query/Chrome_Safari_db_data.png

FF& IE DB entry:
http://redcontour.com/query/FF_IE_data.png

The problem with this is that I'm not always returning the data for use in a div of similar width to the textarea box it was originally put into so it looks very strange the data not running the entire width of the div.

Any ideas?

POST UPDATED - Below is the validation before the data then gets sent into the db, the example above is data I've inputted and I haven't done anything different in both of the experiments in the browsers, so I don't know how the link breaks are getting in.

```
// Create a function for escaping the data.
function escape_data ($data) {
    global $dbc; // Need the connection.
    if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data, $dbc);
} // End of function.

// Check for about.
if (empty($_POST['about'])) {
    $a = FALSE;
    $message .= '<p>About you description missing.</p>';
} else {
    $a = escape_data(strip_tags($_POST['about']));
}
```

HTML code for inputting the data.

```
<textarea class="ed_text_box" name="about" wrap="physical" rows="5" onKeyDown="textCounter(document.details.about,document.details.ed_text_box,500)" onKeyUp="textCounter(document.details.about,document.details.ed_text_box,500)">I'm a traveller at heart, having lived in Portugal and England. Love camping and getting away from it all, whether it's walking the Cornish coast or canoeing in the Brecon Beacons.</textarea>
```

the text counter just stops users putting too much copy into the field, i've tested it without it and I get the same problem. the css is also below so all info is available in this post.

```
.ed_text_box {width:394px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; margin:0 0 20px 0; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, SunSans-Regular, Sans-Serif; font-weight:normal; color:#564b47;}
```

any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: 1) Try and avoid mono-spaced fonts (like the text in the second image) if this is something you are concerned about. 2) Have any `&nbsp;`s leaked in there? `&nbsp;` is a *non-breaking* space and some browsers may treat it as something that will not break, so multiple words separated with them may wrap to the next line.

Comment: There is something else going on. Your problem is there are line breaks in the text. I think it's highly unlikely they are being added by Chrome/Safari. More likely the user typed them in, or your code added them somehow. Can you verify this and update your question?

Comment: I've updated the post with a bit more info. This is happening across all the textareas on the site, although they all use the same code structure.

Comment: @DaveRandom "`&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space and some browsers may treat it as something that will not break"  I should hope they do. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol Fair comment, although have a play with IE6 and try and find some consistent behaviour...

Comment: I'm managed to find a temporary fix using ereg_replace to change any \r\n to normal html line breaks and then run it through the stripslashes and strip_tags. if anyone knows of neater piece of code that would be great. this is a browsers issue though which surprised me.

Comment: Does `wrap="physical"` do the same as `wrap="hard"`? If that's the case, then that's your problem.

Comment: @zrvan thank you, I'm looked into this a bit more, wrap="soft" is what I should be using. wrap="physical" isn't supported cross browser. this is a much simpler fix!

Comment: @rC_Skip I've added the suggestion as an answer, which it more correctly was. Hope it works for you and if it does, you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely these browsers respond to the `wrap="physical"` attribute on the `<textarea />`. According to [THIS](http://arnspublishing.com/QuickRef/textarea.html) the attribute is IE-specific and corresponds to `wrap="hard"`, meaning the line-breaks visible to the user are included in the data sent to the server. What you want is the `wrap="soft"` behavior, which I'm quite certain is the default across all browser -- so there would be no need to specify it.

Granted neither Chrome nor Safari are IE and you note that IE works fine, but I'd suspect that's your issue non the less.

Comment: I've just swapped all `wrap="physical"` to `wrap="soft"` and this looks to have worked. Finally got there, thanks again for your help on this. FYI for anyone else this post is related to a previous one on this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170667/google-chrome-textareas-wrapping-and-adding-line-breaks-help)